# Video Player That Shows Milliseconds

Tags: mediaplayer

Is there a video player for Linux that shows the milliseconds of time elapsed?

There's an [extension for VLC](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php?content=149618&forumpage=2&PHPSESSID=fee4d78b932f9cb53441a6ddba589908), but according to comments at the link it doesn't work with newer versions.

Comment: You could try `avidemux` (with `gtk` or `qt` interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a VLC extension known as the time extension, it only works on VLC v2.0.x. You can check the tutorial here http://www.latestsolution.com/2016/06/Show-VLC-Timing-In-Millisecond.html

Answer (score 6):

[mplayer](https://mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html) should be able to do that:

`mplayer -osdlevel 3 -osd-fractions 1 filename`

see manual for details on the parameters:

```
-osd-fractions <0-2>
       Set how fractions of seconds of the current timestamp are printed on the OSD:
          0    Do not display fractions (default).
          1    Show the first two decimals.
          2    Show  approximated  frame count within current second.  This frame count is
               not accurate but only an approximation.  For variable fps,  the  approxima‐
               tion is known to be far off the correct frame count.
```

tested with mplayer 1.3.0.

Answer (score 3):

SMPlayer.

**In status bar:**

Options -> Statusbar

- Show the current time with milliseconds

**OSD (on screen display):**

View -> OSD

- Show times with milliseconds
- Volume + Seek + Timer

For OSD it can need to install **mpv**. Activate *mpv* in *SMPlayer* here:
Options - Preferences - General - Multimedia engine - mpv

Answer (score 1):

Run mplayer in a terminal using `mplayer -osd-fractions 1 yourfile`

Comment: Tx! That works great. https://i.imgur.com/xi0ZJB3.png